# insert header when table split in iTexPdf

Tags: android, itext

I'm using iTextPdf 5.4.5. I have a table with many rows in it, and when the table auto-splits to the next page, I want to put header in next page starting of that table. Like suppose i have 5 tables and if table 2 splits then in next page header will say `"continue from table 2"`.

I'm trying to use the PdfPTableEventSplit interface, as follows:

```
public class PdfTable implements PdfPTableEventSplit
{

@Override
public void splitTable(PdfPTable arg0) {
    System.out.println("split table");

}

@Override
public void tableLayout(PdfPTable arg0, float[][] arg1, float[] arg2, int arg3, int arg4, PdfContentByte[] arg5) {
    System.out.println("table layout");

}

@Override
public void afterSplitTable(PdfPTable arg0, PdfPRow arg1, int arg2) {
    System.out.println("after split");
    arg0.addCell(new Phrase("testing"));
}
```

But none of the methods is called when table splits.

Comment: Did you add the event to the table?

Comment: yeah i am adding. I removed that part of code

Comment: Please create a SSCCE (see http://sscce.org if you're not familiar with the concept). Also: `arg0.addCell(new Phrase("testing"));` is an illegal statement in your snippet. You should treat `arg0` as a read-only object.

Comment: Show me some code! No SSCCE, no answer.

Comment: Answer has been provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25551023/241291