# iText PdfPTableEventForwarder not getting called when expected,

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I will freely admit this is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21284015/241291), but there has been no answer there and I think I can add more info.

Using iText 5.5.0

What I need: A zebra-striped table where there is *not* a top/bottom border between cells, but there is a bottom border to the table itself, or whenever the table is split over multiple pages.  I have a small snip here from a test run using "lorem ipsum" and other arbitrary data.  I partially cut off the footer that says "Page 1 of 2" but this table does
have additional rows that continue on page 2.  I want this table to look more or less as it is, with the addition of a bottom border on the last row of the page.

[image]

I am trying to implement a PdfPTableEventForwarder via an anonymous inner class.  I have a method that looks like this:

```
public PdfPTable createStandardTable(int columnCount, int headerRows) {
    PdfPTableEventForwarder tableEvent = new PdfPTableEventForwarder()
    {
        // begin another anonymous inner class extends PdfPTableEventForwarder
        @Override
        public void splitTable(PdfPTable table) {
            PdfPRow lastRow = table.getRow(table.getLastCompletedRowIndex());
            for (PdfPCell cell : lastRow.getCells()) {
                cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT + Rectangle.RIGHT + Rectangle.BOTTOM);
            }
        }
        // end anonymous inner class extends PdfPTableEventForwarder
    };

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnCount);
    table.setSpacingBefore(TABLE_SPACING);
    table.setSpacingAfter(TABLE_SPACING);
    table.setWidthPercentage(TABLE_WIDTH_PERCENT);
    table.setHeaderRows(headerRows);
    table.setTableEvent(tableEvent);
    return table;
}
```

And elsewhere I create my table like so:

```
// Details of code to create document and headers not shown
PdfPTable table = createStandardTable(12, 2);
// Details of code to build table not shown, but includes cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT + Rectangle.RIGHT)
document.add(table);
```

I have run this in debugger with a break point at the first line inside `splitTable` and find that the event is only called once.  I would expect it to call twice: first when page 1 ends and page 2 is beginning, second when the table is complete.  Further, I have 30 rows in this table plus 2 header rows: 25 rows fit on page 1 with the header, the last five rows are on page 2.  The debugger tells me that `table.getLastCompletedRowIndex()`
evaluates to 32, not to 27 as expected at the end of page 1.

Indeed, the final result saved to my file has a bottom border on the last row on page 2, but not one on page 1.  Neither one had a border prior to adding the PdfPTableEventForwarder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you have a table with 10 rows and you split one row, you have a total number of 11 rows. That explains your confusion about the row count.
- I don't understand why you use the `PdfPTableEventForwarder` when you only need one event. `PdfPTableEventForwarder` is used when you have a series of `PdfPTable` events.
- Changing the cells in table or cell events is **not correct**. This will **never** work. When an event is triggered, the cell has already been rendered. If you want to draw a bottom border, draw a bottom border in a sequence of `lineTo()`, `moveTo()` and `stroke()` commands using the coordinates handed to you in the `tableLayout()` method of your `PdfPTableEvent` implementation.

An example that is different from what you need, but in a way similar can be found here: [PressPreviews.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=95). No before or after split is needed, you just need the basic `PdfPTableEvent` interface and a `tableLayout()` method that looks like this.

```
public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] width, float[] height,
        int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
    float widths[] = width[0];
    float x1 = widths[0];
    float x2 = widths[widths.length - 1];
    float y = height[height.length - 1];
    PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
    cb.moveTo(x1, y);
    cb.lineTo(x2, y);
    cb.stroke();
}
```

I could be mistaken regarding the `y` value, but I hope you get the general idea.